# A prime $p$ splits in $K$ if and only if $P(x)$ splits into distinct linear factors modulo $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/185039) answer, one can read:

> Let $P \in \Bbb Z[X]$.
>   Let $K$ be the splitting field of $P(x)$. A prime $p$ splits in $K$ if and only if$^1$ $P(x)$ splits into distinct linear factors modulo $p$.
>
> <sup>1</sup> With finitely many exceptions, related to the fact that the ring of integers in $K$ may not be $\mathbb{Z}[x]/P(x)$.

**Question:**
I would like to know the precise statement of this claim (e.g. what are these "finitely many exceptions"), and how to prove this statement.

---

I am aware of Dedekind's factorization theorem, stated [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/dedekindf.pdf) :

> Let $K$ be  a  number   field  and $a \in O_K$ such  that $K=\Bbb Q(a)$. 
>   Let $f(T)$ be  the  minimal  polynomial  of $a$ in $\Bbb Z[T]$.  For  any  prime $p$ not  dividing $[O_K:\Bbb Z[a]]$,write
>   $$f(T) = \pi_1(T)^{e_1}\cdots \pi_r(T)^{e_r} \pmod p,$$ where  the $\pi(T)$'s  are  distinct  monic  irreducibles  in $\Bbb Fp[T]$.   Then $(p) =pO_K$ factors  into prime ideals as
>   $$(p) = P_1^{e_1}\cdots P_r^{e_r},$$ where there is a bijection between the $P_i$'s and $\pi(T)$'s such that $N(P_i)=p^{deg(\pi_i)}$.

In order to prove $\Longleftarrow$ in the statement above, I would like to apply Dedekind's factorization theorem. But I don't know how I could take $P(T)=f(T)$, i.e. $P$ is the minimal polynomial of an element $a \in O_K$ such that $K=\Bbb Q(a)$ (only knowing that the roots of $P$ are $r_1,\dots,r_n$ such that $K=\Bbb Q(r_1,\dots,r_n)$).

Moreover, I don't see how to get "$\implies$".

Here are some related questions: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567456), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953383), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897672/), [(4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74889/).

Answer (score -1):

Apply the Dedekind theorem to $\mathbb{Q}(r_i)$ and use the fact that if a prime splits in a several fields then it splits in their composite.

Comment: Thank you. But what is the precise statement of the claim? And how to prove $\implies$ ?

Comment: You can't finish the proof on your own ? It might be a long wait.